# Implementing object detection in DJI Mavic 2 pro in real time

Tags: software, video, photography, dji-mavic-air-2

I have developed a model in python (pytorch)  for detecting specific kind of objects,
Now I'd  like to embed and load this model into the my DJI Mavic 2 pro,
According to posts I understand I need to to write code on the drone which should be c++,
Is there any suggestions how can I start capturing live footage and pass those frames into the model?

Any helpful resources/examples/github repos will be helpful

Comment: Were you able to achieve this? I am looking at using the Windows SDK as mentioned by @andrew

Answer (score 3):

That's a fascinating project, but I'm not sure it's possible on a DJI drone. The firmware is closed source and not designed for easy modification.

I don't know if it's possible to replace the DJI firmware with an open source project like [iNav](https://github.com/iNavFlight/inav) or if you would need to build a new drone from scratch around an iNav capable flight controller.

You might also find that you need a more powerful processor to run real-time image analysis.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do so.

Check this API [reference](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-api-reference/index.html). They also provide this [Windows SDK](https://developer.dji.com/windows-sdk/) which can be of use to your needs. My experience is with an on-board SDK which I used to avoid objects using a custom ultrasonic transceiver. Knowing how popular python is I assume there is some C++ wrapper somewhere which can translate C++ functions to python somehow, but more research should be done here.